# read input from html forms, execute local program,output results

Tags: html, executable

I have a question that will help me understand how stuff works and investigate feasibility of a bigger plan I have in mind.

Simply given - lets assume that all things run locally - I am wondering if it is possible to:

- create an html page with a form that will prompt the user to enter
  the local path of an input file inputFile.dat
- this  input file will be fed to a c++ exe program that expects it for input
- the c++ exe  file will run (this exe file depends on libraries etc but lets     assume all are local here)
- ...  and will output the result on screen

It sounds simple, but is it?

Many thanks folks!

Comment: are you expecting the output to be shown without the page being reloaded?

Comment: As long as your c++ program is named Apache :-)

Comment: EDIT:  I  am expecting to press  a button and "onclick" to make the program run and get the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is definitely possible, if you want to use PHP or some other scripting language.

- Create a form on your web page

  - Add the directory of the program
  - Add the directory of the data
- When submitted, use the PHP (or other language) `exec` function ([docs](https://www.php.net/function.exec)) to execute the program, with the supplied data as argument
- The `exec` function returns output from the program.
- Display the output as wished on your page.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you Hidde, I prefer js to php that I know a bit better. But I believe your view will help me find my way with js as well. Thanks

Comment: The thing is that with JS you cannot run a program on your own machine, as the browser sandboxes the JS environment. Otherwise any website could execute any program on your computer, a big security risk.